# What is a good set and forget file version tracking / backup application for windows?

Tags: windows, svn, version

When I make changes to files, I keep on finding myself "saving as" and adding the current date to the file. It slows me down, and it creates a bunch of files that clot my folder. I would prefer to be able to Right Click on a file from the File Explorer and select to save different versions of this file, so that each time I save it, it saves a copy somewhere, that I can access in the future if necessary.

Is there any application that achieves this?

Comment: Install a backup program like Crashplan.

Comment: Which windows version are you using?

Comment: @Zoredache: $25 a year to be able to track changes, right?

Comment: @Luiz Angelo: Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever heard of [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com)?
For a free account, it can record changes of your files for up to a month.
 and your files will also be safe in the cloud.
For a pro account(9.99$ per month), it saves **unlimited history** of your files.
and it's the best set and forget solution.

Comment: I do have dropbox, but I have to save my files in a dropbox folder, I can't just tell it to track changes to a file that is in my current folder structure.

Comment: Actually you can. For example, your dropbox folder is D:\Dropbox, the folder you want to track is D:\work, you can create a junction using this command:mklink /D D:\Dropbox\work D:\work. it's pretty much like a symbolic link in linux.